# Would I benefit using Cloud run instead of Cloud Functions? Where does it fit in GCP?

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-run

I use Cloud Functions for most of my backend requirements. What additional benefit does Cloud Run provide to an existing Cloud functions user? Both are managed, has autoscaling, handles HTTP and are run in GCP.

Where would Cloud Run fit in [Google Cloud Platform](https://youtu.be/g0dN8Hkh5H8)?

[image: GCP stack]

References : [GCP explained - Medium](https://medium.com/google-cloud/gcp-the-google-cloud-platform-compute-stack-explained-c4ebdccd299b)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Cloud Functions server instances handle requests *in serial*, and this is not  configurable.  Cloud Run instances handle requests *in parallel*, and the level of parallelism per instance is configurable.  This can potentially save you money, if you understand how best to configure a server instance, given the performance characteristics of the code you deploy.

Cloud Functions requires you to choose from among provided language and runtime configurations that are not configurable.  Cloud Run lets you run any type of backend configuration you want, assuming that it simply exposes an HTTP endpoint on port 8080.

Cloud Functions provides those selected language and runtime configurations without requiring that you do anything other than deploy code that targets one of those configurations.  Cloud Run requires that you supply a docker configuration that establishes the runtime environment (which is more work).

Cloud Functions lets you establish triggers on a wide variety of events that can come from a variety of Cloud and Firebase products.  Cloud Run (currently) can be triggered via HTTP requests, PubSub push and a narrow selection of Cloud products (such as Cloud Scheduler and Cloud Tasks).

Cloud Functions requires that you only run your code within the managed provided environments.  Cloud Run allows you to take your docker configuration and run it anywhere docker is supported, including [GKE](https://cloud.google.com/kubernetes-engine/), where you gain more control over the server instances.

Comment: Cloud function does auto-scaling, right? Although there are no configuration options. https://cloud.google.com/functions/docs/concepts/exec#auto-scaling_and_concurrency

Comment: Yes, it auto scales.

Answer (score 2):

Google Cloud Run fits into your Serverless layer but as a container. The container infrastructure is managed for you.

Cloud Functions are limited in respect to the libraries, languages, and runtimes supported.

Cloud Run removes those limitations. You can use any language, combination of libraries and runtime that supports running within a container.

One limitation is that there is only one internal port `$PORT` which defaults to 8080 today. Externally both HTTP and HTTPS are supported. Both HTTP and HTTPS map to `$PORT`.

One big plus is that Cloud Run supports custom DNS names and custom SSL certificates. You can host your website on Cloud Run. As an experiment, I set up WordPress and Cloud SQL on Cloud Run and assigned it a DNS domain name with an SSL certificate.

Comment: _Off-topic_, if you managed to install WordPress on Cloud Run without writing new files to disk (uploads, wp-config.php etc) please write a blog post! There was a question here asking about it, too. (Plus it’d be an interesting read.)

Comment: @AhmetB-Google - Actually I am writing an article to document this. It might come out this weekend on my site. I have several articles on Cloud Run covering security, custom DNS names, HTTP protocols, etc. Just been so busy at work to write everything up.

Comment: So Cloud Run is much better than using rewrite rules 
 for a custom domain for Cloud functions. https://firebase.google.com/docs/hosting/functions#direct_requests_to_function

Comment: I have not experimented with rewrite rules for Cloud Functions. Creating a domain (www.example.com) is very easy with Cloud Run. Google even provisions the SSL certificate for you. Keep in mind that Cloud Run uses a CNAME for DNS. This precludes using example.com as normally you do not want to use a CNAME for the domain root. If Google adds Cloud Run as a backend for the HTTP Load Balancer, then you will be able to use Cloud Run for everything. I am currently using it for subdomains and no problems so far. Cloud Functions still has a lot of use cases, just some of them will move to Cloud Run.